# UseCase: Two containers requesting the complete memory on node

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following use case:

- Suppose `node1 has 4GB RAM` and `node2 has 4GB RAM.`
- `pod1` has requested "resources.requests" of 2GB.
- `pod2` has requested "resources.requests" of 2GB.
- suppose "scheduler" sends both the pods on node1.
- `pod1` occupies 250MB and `pod2` occupies 250MB on node1.
- Now, `pod3 comes` in and it doesn't have resources declaration.
- suppose "scheduler" also sends the pod3 also on node1.

Here, if pod3 starts occupying space and gets 2GB space leaving only 1.5GB available on node1.

What would happen?

Will it evict `pod1` and `pod2` from node1 and move them to node2?

Comment: Scheduling of pod to node will only happen if the requested resources are there in the node

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal my question is more related to eviction of pod1 and pod2. I understand the scheduling portion

Comment: In your stated example or use case Pod eviction will not happen for already deployed pods on nodes.  Please refer following link how pods will be evicted from node.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation you describe, where the actual memory usage is

| Pod | Memory Requested | Memory Used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.0 GiB | 0.25 GiB |
| 2 | 2.0 GiB | 0.25 GiB |
| 3 | 0.0 GiB | 2.0 GiB |
| Free | 0.0 GiB | 1.5 GiB |

Since there is free memory, nothing gets evicted.  Since the third pod didn't request any memory, it "fits" on that node given only the resource requests.

But now let's say both pods 1 and 2 start doing real work, and the situation changes to

| Pod | Memory Requested | Memory Used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.0 GiB | 1.0 GiB |
| 2 | 2.0 GiB | 1.0 GiB |
| 3 | 0.0 GiB | 2.0 GiB |
| Free | 0.0 GiB | 0.0 GiB |

and the Kubernetes eviction algorithm gets triggered.  By [the normal rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#pod-selection-for-kubelet-eviction), the first two pods are within their resource *requests*, but the third one is substantially over.  That means that pod 3 will get evicted in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

To address your query, the answer is no, `pod 1` and `pod 2` won't be kicked off of `node 1` and relocated to `node 2`. Since `node 1` can still accommodate the 2GB resource required by `pod 3` in the use case you specified, `pod 3` will continue to occupy `node 1` after both `pod 1` and `pod 2` have occupied 500mb each, leaving `node 1` with 3.5GB.

---

According to my understanding of Kubernetes, `pod` that have been first deployed to a `node` will be prioritized, use the necessary resources, and not be relocated or transferred to other nodes. If a new `pod` were generated and a node does not have enough memory, the scheduler will assign the new pod to the node that has enough memory. Assuming there is no other node created, then the `pod` will be tagged as unschedulable.

This means that `pod 1` and `pod 2` will remain on `node 1`, and `pod 3` will be deployed there as well, unless `node 1` is unable to provide the required memory, in which case `pod 3` will be relocated to `node 2`.

*Note: All figures here are all used as examples in this topic, in real life this is not the case, as other services running that also consumes resources.*